# Send variables from "browser_action" to "content_scripts"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am so new about making Chrome extension and somethings I will try :

I will to send JS variables from "browser_action" to "content_scripts"

---

```
"browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "src/browser_action/index.html"
},
"content_scripts": [
   {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["src/inject/inject.js"]
   }
]
```

---

Example : If...

**src/browser_action/main.js :** *(browser_action)*

```
var MyVar = "Hello world";
```

And how to send `MyVar` to **src/inject/inject.js** ? Like..

```
// What function I should do before to alert()?
if (typeof MyVar !== 'undefined') {
   alert(MyVar);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send message(or data) from background to content script, you can use [chrome.tabs.sendMessage()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage). But you need to specify which tab(using `tabId`) to send it to. You should read [message passing in extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

**Example :**

*Sending a message to the content script in the selected tab*

**main.js**

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.farewell);
  });
});
```

On the receiving end, you need to set up an [chrome.runtime.onMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage) event listener to handle the message

**inject.js:**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
      sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
  });
```

Comment: Thanks. But how to get `message` without opening the "browser_action" ? possible ?

Comment: Use a background script : https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages

Answer (score 0):

I did it with `chrome.storage` [#ref](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage)

**Example :**

Add "storage" permission on **manifest.json**

```
"permissions": [
   "storage"
]
```

**On main.js** *(browser_action)*

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({'user':{email:'hello@world.com'}});
```

**On inject.js** *(content_scripts)*

```
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function(c,a){
   chrome.storage.sync.get('user',function(o){
      if(!$.isEmptyObject(o)){ // Check via jQuery function
          // Do somethings...
          console.log(o.user.email);
      }
   });
});
```